# Is my understanding of interpreter and compiler correct?

Tags: compiler-construction, terminology, interpreter

I was wondering if my understanding
    about interpreter and compiler is
    correct:

1. I think a compiler only does translation from source code to binary
   code, while an interpreter not only does the translation work but
   also execute what is generated after compilation.
2. Does an interpreter always have a part for compilation?
3. Does compiler always not execute the binary code it generates?

Sorry for asking dumb questions. Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

1. You are right about the compiler but wrong about the interpreter. Interpreter don't have to translate anything. It just read piece of code and "interprets" it - executes what it have read. For example, it reads `1 + 2` and then executes function `sum(1, 2)`.
2. No. Interpreter may use compilation just for optimization purposes (like it is done in HotSpot JVM which uses JIT compilation).
3. Well, the job of the compiler is to "compile" - to translate source code to binary code. That's all. So the answer for your question - Yes. It is not its job.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler translate from the source language to *something* else, including bytecode or a simpler language - it doesn't have to be machine code and it may very dump a human-readable representation. If the source and output language are at about the same level of abstraction, some prefer terms like "converter", but those are compilers as well.

An interpreter, on the other hand, doesn't output code. It just builds the internal data structures from the source code, similar to what compilers do before code generation - only the don't create another equivalent program in another language but *executes* the program right away. Note that a (not JIT-compiling) virtual machine executing bytecode is an interpreter as well. So CPython isn't an interpreter for Python, but a compiler from Python to CPython bytecode - and an interpreter for that bytecode.

So your definition of compiler in #1 isn't broad enough while the definition of interpreter actually names a combination ofcompiler and interpreter (you're not to blame, it's a very common approach taken by many languages commonly - but wrongly - called "interpreted"). #2 is false, as interpreters don't output code (which would make a compiler) while #3 is correct (you can hook it up with an interpreter for the output code, but that's still a different program).

Comment: Well, what you call a "compiler" is "translator" in fact. And compiler is a translator which translates the sources to machine code.

Comment: @xappymah: That's indeed a synonym. But as the answer says, compilers are **not** limited in their output format. In fact, there's a buttload of compilers whose output is not even close to machine code.

Comment: well, ok. It just the question about terms :) I prefer to distinguish those terms because it becomes very messy when you work both with translators and compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers translate an input language into an output language. The output language does not have to be binary code, e.g. you can compile Java to Javascript like GWT. An interpreter executes a source language directly by mapping concepts in the source language directly to operations. The source language does not have to be text e.g. the Java bytecode interpreter. An interpreter usually has a parsing step, in which it translates the physical representation of the source code into an internal executable representation. This is different to compilation in that the internal representation is a direct representation of the source, e.g. a syntax tree and not a transformed (optimized) equivalent.